# How to change EF CodeFirst multiplicity from one to zero/one?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship, entities

Imagine I have two entities:

```
 public class User{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Country{
    public Guid CountryId {get; set;}
    public virtual List<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

If I try to add a user who doesn't belong to any country, I get an `UpdateException` on the `SaveChanges` command:

> Entities in 'SLContext.User' participate in the 'Country_Users'
>   relationship. 0 related 'Country_Users_Source' were found. 1
>   'Country_Users_Source' is expected

I believe this issue is related to the autogenerated one-to-many relationship. How can I set this multiplicity to 0.1 ---> * ?

Comment: What are you using for Mapping? FluentAPI or DataAnnotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **FluentAPI**, configuration for `User` Entity should be :

```
   HasOptional(x=> x.Country)
       .WithMany(x=> x.Users);
```

And your User Entity :

```
   public class User{
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
   }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: In this case I would have to add a navigation property on the User's entity, is this mandatory?

Comment: Yes you have to add navigation property for `Country` Entity in `User`'s Entity.